# Which features can I install into IIS / Windows Server 2012 without downtime?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

Is there a list or a document that shows which features can be installed safely without causing downtime to an IIS / Windows Server instance?

In particular I am looking for if installing WebSocket feature support will require a reboot, or app pool recycling (which causes about 10 minutes of downtime in this case).

We are using SignalR and didn't realize the web socket feature was not installed in our production environment, and it is causing SignalR to downgrade to less savory transports (long polling, forever frames, etc...) and causing browser connection limit issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you have to restart the IIS project only. But you need to restart the service for making the change effective.

Comment: We had to reboot the server. We decided to wait until a safe period of time late at night when our user level was low.